# Accessing cookies in a subdomain

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have two domains www.a.com and b.a.com. I have a cookie testCookie with a domain b.a.com. Is it possible to delete this cookie from the domain www.a.com? I have been unable to do so - is the "www" the culprit?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a wildcard cookie domain like `.a.com` in order to access it from `www.a.com` and `b.a.com`.